# Pipe Node stdout in realtime

Tags: node.js, spawn, pty

I have a `spawn` process running a `docker pull` and I'm using the following:

```js
const proc = spawn('docker', [ 'pull', 'some/container' ], { env: process.env, cwd: process.env.HOME })
proc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

As it runs it breaks up and downloads the individual SHA's and the above works *pretty* well, however, it puts each response on a new line. I'm curious if there's a way to emulate the "normal" output so each line writes as it pull the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just piping to `process.stdout`, then you could just set the [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) option like:

```
const proc = spawn('docker', [
  'pull',
  'some/container'
], {
  env: process.env,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, 'pipe']
});
```

The end result being that `docker` will now see its stdout as a TTY (assuming this node script is being run from a terminal/pty of course) and not a pipe.